How can I get data based on role in Supabase? (RLS problem)
I'm new to Supabase(PostgreSQL) and struggling with writing RLS.
I have 'users' and 'roles' tables.
There are 5 roles - SUPER_ADMIN, ADMIN, CLIENT, SPECIALIST, INTERNAL_OPERATOR.
Now, I'm going to write RLS on 'users' table so only users with SUPER_ADMIN role can do CRUD users.
'users' and 'roles' tables has relationship based on role_id in 'users' table.
Please help me.
CREATE POLICY "Allow SUPER_ADMIN access" 
    ON users
    FOR ALL
    USING (
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM roles 
            WHERE roles.id = users.role_id 
            AND roles.name = 'SUPER_ADMIN'
        )
    );

I wrote like this.
But when I log in with SUPER_ADMIN role, I'm only fetchings users who has SUPER_ADMIN role
